# Physical Interpretation of Partition Function with Background Field

Tags: quantum-field-theory, statistical-mechanics, field-theory, feynman-diagrams

Integrals of the form
$$\langle{\phi(x_1)\cdots\phi(x_n)}\rangle=\frac{1}{Z}\int\mathcal{D}\phi\,e^{-\frac{1}{\hbar}S(\phi)}\phi(x_1)\cdots\phi(x_n)$$
can be evaluated by considering Feynman diagrams with tails labelled with $\phi(x_1),\dots\phi(x_n)$. I have recently come across with a related notion of computing
$$\frac{1}{Z}\int\mathcal{D}\phi\,e^{-\frac{1}{\hbar}(S_0(\phi)+I(\phi+a))}$$
where $S_0$ is the free action and $I$ is the interaction term. From what I have understood, this can be computed in exactly the same way labelling the tails with $a$'s at different points $x$'s and integrating over the latter.

What is the physical interpretation of this last path integral? What is the meaning of the background field $a$?

Comment: Have you read the chapter in Schwarz on background fields?

Comment: It's a classical field you expand around which satisfies the euler lagrange EOM